# Access a control that we made with Itemplate

Tags: asp.net

There is a templated control
that we want to access the inner template control's properties ,

How can I achieve this ?
All I want is :
ibtnPrev.Visible = false ;

```
class CFooterTemplate : ITemplate
{

    Label lblPaging;
    ImageButton ibtnPrev;
    ImageButton ibtnNext;

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        lblPaging = new Label();
        ibtnPrev = new ImageButton();
        ibtnNext = new ImageButton();

        container.Controls.Add(ibtnNext);
        container.Controls.Add(lblPaging);
        container.Controls.Add(ibtnPrev);
```

}

---

Access an Inner control and Change one of it's properties

```
        listCase.FooterTemplate = new CFooterTemplate();
```

Now e.g we want to set the **visibility** of **ibtnPrev** to false
How many ways do we have , and what is your suggested method ,
thanks

Just I want to do this
    ibtnPrev.Visible = false ;

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [find the control by its ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) and then cast the control to its type.

Comment: whitin the 
listCase.FindControl("lblPaging") ;
is enough ?
or listCase.FooterTemplate.FindControl("lblPaging") ;

I think the ID will be changed during the generation of the control ,
Is it a certain way to find the ID here or I must do It manually ?

thanks

Comment: The ID will be changed when the page renders but FindControl will execute before the page is rendered so it is safe to use the short ID.  Try to restrict the search width of FindControl by searching within the closest parent element that you can to get the best performance.

Comment: These are the Generated IDs :
CustPanel1_ctl01_ctl04_pnlCustNav For : pnlCustNav
CustPanel1$ctl01$ctl04$ibtnPrev   For : ibtnPrev

Do we have any possibility to make them as simple as we defined :
e.g change : CustPanel1$ctl01$ctl04$ibtnPrev   to : ibtnPrev

or not ?

Comment: When you use FindControl use it like this: FindControl("pnlCustNav") not FindControl("CustPanel1_ctl01_ctl04_pnlCustNav").

Comment: This way all my controls return null ,
ibtnPrev  = ((ImageButton)listCust.FindControl("ibtnPrev"));

Any idea ?

Comment: In both ways it knows my control as null ,
also instead of the datalist I tried the control's FindControl method , in all of them my controls are known as null